# css file integrity check fails after docker build

Tags: css, docker, checksum, integrity

I have the following issue.

```
Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for resource 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/uistatic/css/bootstrap4.0.0.min.css' with computed SHA-256 integrity 'xLbtJkVRnsLBKLrbKi53IAUvhEH/qUxPC87KAjEQBNo='. The resource has been blocked.
```

And this is happening when i put my site into docker with building this Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6

COPY skfront /app

WORKDIR /app

RUN mkdir -p /static/resources
RUN mkdir logs
RUN mkdir certs

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
RUN python3 manage.py collectstatic --settings blog_site.settings

EXPOSE 8080

CMD python3 website.py -l 0.0.0.0 -p 8080
```

This css is static file that doesn't change.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that building Dockerfile on Windows can mess-up the final image.
When I build my site under Linux there ware no integrity errors.

Comment: Haha, building docker images is what got me to leave Windows too. :)